# How do I select Link tag in React Router Dom with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm very new to React.
And I'm in trouble with select Link tags in CSS.
I found that I can solve with give classname to Link tag or directly give style attribute, but I wanna select all of the Link tags.
How I solve this problem?
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper React way would be to wrap the React Router `Link` with your own component that applies styles.

```
import { Link as RouterLink } from 'react-router-dom';

function Link(props) {
    return <RouterLink className="myClassname" {...props} />;
}

export default Link;
```

Then you can use your `Link` component just as you would the native `Link` component and the class name will be applied automatically.

For a quicker, dirtier approach, the React Router Link object is simply an `<a>` tag under the hood. In a global stylesheet, you can simply target `a` to apply styles.

Comment: How do you know that link React Router Link object is simply an <a> tag under the hood? Is there a handbook / cheat sheet / documentation that you can link me to?

Comment: ["...a `<Link>` renders an accessible `<a>` element..."](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#link)